# Live chat room event: Ariane 5 ECA rocket (VA215) to launch the Eutelsat 25B and GSAT 7 satellites (Aug. 29, 2013 at 8:10 p.m. UTC/GMT)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, announcement, scheduled-event

**This is an invitation to attend [our chat room event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay?tab=schedule), where we will be covering the launch of the [Ariane 5 ECA](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Launchers/Launch_vehicles/Ariane_5_ECA) rocket, designated VA215, to launch the [Eutelsat 25B](http://www.eutelsat.com/en/satellites/future-satellites/launch-schedule/EUTELSAT-25B.html) and [GSAT 7](http://www.satbeams.com/satellites?id=2528) satellites.**

[image]

```
Launch date: Aug. 29, 2013
Launch window: 20:30-21:20 GMT (4:30-5:20 p.m. EDT)
Launcher: Ariane 5 ECA rocket
Payloads: Eutelsat 25B and GSAT 7 satellites
Launch site: ELA-3, Kourou, French Guiana
```

Eutelsat 25B, also known as Es'hail 1, will provide *Ku-band* and *Ka-band* direct television broadcasting, enterprise communications and government services over Europe, North Africa and the Middle East for Eutelsat and ictQatar.

GSAT 7 will provide multi-band communications services for the Indian Navy.

**Chat event will start 20 minutes before the first launch window time.**

> **[Mission Update](http://arianespace.com/news-mission-update/2013/1090.asp)**
>
> **The go-ahead is given for Arianespace’s heavy-lift Ariane 5 mission to
>   orbit EUTELSAT 25B/Es’hail 1 and GSAT-7**
>  August 27, 2013 – Ariane
>   Flight VA215
>
> Arianespace’s fourth Ariane 5 mission of 2013 has been approved for
>   liftoff on Thursday with two communications satellites to provide
>   relay coverage over the Middle East, North Africa and Central Asia,
>   along with the Indian land mass.
>
> [image: Ariane 5 ECA rocket, designated VA215]
>
> The authorization followed today’s successful launch readiness review
>   conducted at the Spaceport in French Guiana.  This procedure – held
>   prior to all Arianespace missions – validated the “go” status of the
>   launcher, its dual payload of the EUTELSAT 25B/Es’hail 1 and GSAT-7
>   satellites, the Spaceport’s infrastructure and the system of downrange
>   tracking stations.
>
> With today’s review, the Ariane 5 is now cleared for rollout tomorrow
>   from the Spaceport’s Final Assembly Building to the ELA-3 launch zone
>   – where it will be readied for liftoff on August 29 during a 50-minute
>   launch window opening at 5:30 p.m. local time in French Guiana.
>
> The Ariane 5 is to deliver an estimated total lift performance of
>   9,790 kg. – including EUTELSAT 25B/Es’hail 1 and GSAT-7, along with
>   hardware for the launcher’s dual-payload deployment system.
>
> EUTELSAT 25B/Es’hail 1 – which was built by Space Systems/Loral (SSL)
>   – will ride in the upper position of Ariane 5’s payload “stack,” to be
>   deployed first during the 34-minute flight sequence. Once in orbit,
>   the spacecraft will be used by European telecommunications operator
>   Eutelsat Communications and Qatar’s Es’hailSat Satellite Company to
>   deliver Ku-band television broadcasting, telecommunications and
>   government services for the Middle East, North Africa and Central
>   Asia.  Its Ka-band capability will open business opportunities in
>   these regions for both operators.
>
> To be released second as the mission’s lower passenger, India’s GSAT-7
>   was developed by the Indian Space Research Organisation (ISRO) to
>   provide the country with UHF, S-band, C-band and Ku-band relay
>   capacity over the India land mass.  The satellite is adapted from
>   India’s I-2K spacecraft bus, which also was used for the INSAT-3D
>   satellite – lofted by Arianespace’s most recent Ariane 5 mission,
>   performed on July 25.
>
> The Arianespace launch this Thursday is designated Flight VA215 in
>   Arianespace’s numbering system, signifying the 215th flight of an
>   Ariane family vehicle.

---

**[Live Broadcast](http://www.arianespace.tv/)**

Links to follow the event live on the Internet from Guiana Space Center will be posted in our chat room, roughly **20 minutes before the first launch window**, or as the broadcast streams become available.

[image: Local times for the start of the launch window]

---

**Welcome to our chat room - [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay) - where we will discuss this event and post links to live streams covering the launch!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## Arianespace delivers!
>
> #### EUTELSAT 25B/Es’hail 1 and GSAT-7 are orbited by Ariane 5
>
> August 29, 2013 – Ariane Flight VA215
>
> Today marked another mission accomplished for Arianespace’s heavy-lift
> workhorse as it deployed the EUTELSAT 25B/Es’hail 1 and GSAT-7
> spacecraft from the Spaceport in French Guiana – on what is the 57th
> consecutive success for Ariane 5.
>
> [image]
>
> Following an impressive liftoff from the ELA-3 launch zone at 5:30
> p.m. local time, both satellites were deployed into geostationary
> transfer orbit, with EUTELSAT 25B/Es’hail 1 released nearly 28 minutes
> after liftoff, and GSAT-7 separating approximately six minutes later
> to complete the flight sequence.
>
> Ariane 5 delivered a total liftoff performance of 9,790 kg., including
> its two payloads and hardware for the launcher’s dual-payload
> deployment system. Today’s mission represents the 215th launch of an
> Ariane-series vehicle, as well as the 71st liftoff for Ariane 5.
>
> [**Video of the Ariane 5 ECA rocket VA215 launching the Eutelsat 25B
> and GSAT 7 satellites**](http://www.videocorner.tv/videocorner2/a5_vod/index.htm)